# Given a URI, how can I lookup which controller method would serve that URL?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If I have a URI of `/customers/1234/salesOrders` How can I lookup which `@RequestMapping` method would be used if that endpoint was requested?

To be clear, these are not actual requests being made. Our application logs every URI requested and it's now been asked for usage reports of each distinct request mapping (variables removed).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured this one out. If you inject a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` into a controller you can then use it with a `MockHttpServletRequest` to then query which handler method would be used.

```
// Create a mock request with method and URI.
MockHttpServletRequest req = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "/test/abc/000");
// Add request params and other requriements to request object.

// handlerMapping is injected using @Autowired into the class.
HandlerExecutionChain handler = this.handlerMapping.getHandler(req);

String path;
if (handler == null) {
    path = null;
} else {
    path = "";

    // I'm not sure what other types there could be, a test may be
    // required though I'm omitting it.
    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler.getHandler();
    Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();

    RequestMapping reqMapping;

    // If the class has a path mapping, we must also include it.
    if (method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
        reqMapping = method.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        if (reqMapping.value() != null && reqMapping.value().length > 0) {
            path += reqMapping.value()[0];
        }
    }
    reqMapping = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
    if (reqMapping.value() != null && reqMapping.value().length > 0) {
        path += reqMapping.value()[0];
    }
}

// `path' now represents the URI with variable placeholders unexpanded.
```

This approach is enough to get what I'm after. In my case I only want to summarise which endpoints are being used. You will need to also add any content type restrictions, parameters, headers etc to the request so as to resolve the correct endpoint.

If your application is simple enough that there are no request parameter restrictions or no usage of headers then it would not be necessary to add them.

In my test case I simply had the following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ={"/test/", "/test2/" })
public class Controller123 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "abc/{x}")
    public String test(@PathVariable("x") String x) {
        return "test";
    }
```

Which when tested returns `/test/abc/{x}`.